# Issue with formating a date using 'FMMonth' in Oracle and displaying the time correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

The sql below using dual reproduces the issue:

```
SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE) example,
          TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'FMMonth dd, yyyy')
       || ' '
       || TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'hh:MI AM') result_one,
       TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'FMMonth dd, yyyy hh:MI AM') result_two
  FROM DUAL
```

Output:

```
EXAMPLE     RESULT_ONE                  RESULT_TWO
12/4/2012   December 4, 2012 12:00 AM   December 4, 2012 12:0 AM
```

Note how the `RESULT_TWO` output is missing a zero in the minute value of the time, while `RESULT_ONE` does not.  `RESULT_ONE` is my current workaround by appending two separate format instructions.  The issue occurs on any time value where the minutes contain a zero (e.g. 11:02 AM).

Any suggestion on how to perform the `TO_CHAR` without using the `RESULT_ONE` work around?

**Oracle Version Info**

```
> BANNER Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 -
> 64bi PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production CORE  10.2.0.4.0  Production
> TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production NLSRTL Version
> 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply the `fm` modifier to multiple format masks

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE), 'FMMonth dd, yyyy fmhh:MI AM') result_two
  2*   FROM DUAL
SQL> /

RESULT_TWO
------------------------------------------------------
December 4, 2012 12:00 AM
```